# how to get distribution in percent in pandas for v each column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, distribution

how to get the distribution of the values in each column?

I am trying to get the distribution of the values in each column in percent. 
let say I have this data:

```
Date   Region   Rep Item    Units   Unit Cost   Total
1/6/18  East    Jones   Pencil  95   1.99    189.05 
1/23/18 Central Kivell  Binder  50   19.99   999.50 
2/9/18  Central Jardine Pencil  36   4.99    179.64 
2/26/18 Central Gill    Pen 27   19.99   539.73 
3/15/18 West    Sorvino Pencil  56   2.99    167.44 
4/1/18  East    Jones   Binder  60   4.99    299.40 
4/18/18 Central Andrews Pencil  75   1.99    149.25 
5/5/18  Central Jardine Pencil  90   4.99    449.10 
5/22/18 West    Thompson    Pencil  32   1.99    63.68 
6/8/18  East    Jones   Binder  60   8.99    539.40 
6/25/18 Central Morgan  Pencil  90   4.99    449.10 
7/12/18 East    Howard  Binder  29   1.99    57.71 
7/29/18 East    Parent  Binder  81   19.99   1,619.19 
8/15/18 East    Jones   Pencil  35   4.99    174.65 
9/1/18  Central Smith   Desk    2    125.00      250.00 
9/18/18 East    Jones   Pen Set 16   15.99   255.84 
10/5/18 Central Morgan  Binder  28   8.99    251.72 
10/22/18    East    Jones   Pen 64   8.99    575.36 
11/8/18 East    Parent  Pen 15   19.99   299.85 
11/25/18    Central Kivell  Pen Set 96   4.99    479.04 
12/12/18    Central Smith   Pencil  67   1.29    86.43 
12/29/18    East    Parent  Pen Set 74   15.99   1,183.26 
1/15/19 Central Gill    Binder  46   8.99    413.54 
2/1/19  Central Smith   Binder  87   15.00   1,305.00 
2/18/19 East    Jones   Binder  4    4.99    19.96 
3/7/19  West    Sorvino Binder  7    19.99   139.93 
3/24/19 Central Jardine Pen Set 50   4.99    249.50 
4/10/19 Central Andrews Pencil  66   1.99    131.34 
4/27/19 East    Howard  Pen 96   4.99    479.04 
5/14/19 Central Gill    Pencil  53   1.29    68.37 
5/31/19 Central Gill    Binder  80   8.99    719.20 
6/17/19 Central Kivell  Desk    5    125.00      625.00 
7/4/19  East    Jones   Pen Set 62   4.99    309.38 
7/21/19 Central Morgan  Pen Set 55   12.49   686.95 
8/7/19  Central Kivell  Pen Set 42   23.95   1,005.90 
8/24/19 West    Sorvino Desk    3    275.00      825.00 
9/10/19 Central Gill    Pencil  7    1.29    9.03 
9/27/19 West    Sorvino Pen 76   1.99    151.24 
10/14/19    West    Thompson    Binder  57   19.99   1,139.43 
10/31/19    Central Andrews Pencil  14   1.29    18.06 
11/17/19    Central Jardine Binder  11   4.99    54.89 
12/4/19 Central Jardine Binder  94   19.99   1,879.06 
12/21/19    Central Andrews Binder  28   4.99    139.72
```

and I want to get the distribution like:

```
Region: { "central" : 0.558,
           "west" : 0.139,
            "east" : 0.303
}
```

it means that central is 55.8% of the data in region columns.
how can I get it?
in the end, I would like to export everything to excel file.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def get_ddl(df):
    ddl=pd.io.sql.get_schema(df.reset_index(),'table1')
    return ddl

def get_columns(df):
    list=[]
    for col in df.columns:
        list.append(col)
    return list

def distrebution(df,column):
    index = df.groupby(column).count()

    return index



def create_dict(excel_path,sheet_name):
    dict={}
    i=0
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(excel_path)
    df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name)
    columns_list=get_columns(df1)
    while (i<len(columns_list)):

        dict.update({columns_list[i] : [df1[columns_list[i]].min(),df1[columns_list[i]].max()]})

        i=i+1
    return dict
# xls = pd.ExcelFile('/home/sqream/SampleData.xlsx')
# df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'SalesOrders')
# # print(df1)





# df=pd.read_excel('/home/sqream/SampleData.xlsx')
# print(df)
xls = pd.ExcelFile('/home/sqream/SampleData.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'SalesOrders')


x=get_ddl(df1)



dict=create_dict('/home/sqream/SampleData.xlsx','SalesOrders')

res=pd.DataFrame(dict)
res.rename(index={0:'min',1:'max',2: 'distrebution_of_values'}, inplace=True)
print(res)
res.to_excel('/home/sqream/df1.xlsx')

rows_num=(len(df1.index))
x=distrebution(df1,'Region')
d=x.to_dict()
print(d)
```

Comment: `df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict()).to_dict()`

Answer (score 2):

Just use [value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.Region.value_counts(normalize=True)

Central    0.558140
East       0.302326
West       0.139535
Name: Region, dtype: float64
```